# Changing Drawer View Controller Pulley Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm currently using [Pulley](https://github.com/52inc/Pulley) to create a drawer like thing in my map. What I'm trying to do now is when a annotation is selected, it changes the drawer to another one. I've followed the code which the developer said to use on GitHub, however it never works.

Here is my code:

```
func mapView(_ didSelectmapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    print("Annotation selected")

    if let drawer = self.parent as? PulleyViewController {
        let drawerContent = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewDrawerViewController")

        drawer.setDrawerContentViewController(controller: drawerContent, animated: false)
        drawer.setDrawerPosition(position: PulleyPosition.partiallyRevealed, animated: false)

    }
}
```

"Annotation selected" is printed, but the drawer doesn't change. I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Add `print(drawerContent)`and see what it prints?

Comment: I've added it and it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Does your code enter inside `if` statement?

Comment: Yes thats where i put it

Comment: Add `print("inside if")` inside if and see what prints on the console? so that we can be sure

Comment: Nothing is printed. I think 'if let drawer = self.parent as? PulleyViewController {' is not being called.

Comment: Yes I think that is the problem, make sure you rectify that first, self.parent is nil, I guess

Comment: Ok, I'm stuck about how I would go about rectifying that first because in the demo project it works just fine.

Comment: Ok what changes have you made from the original demo?

Comment: Regarding the first if statement, except for the location of where I am doing this there isn't any changes. Inside the if statement, I've just changed the storyboard identifier for the new drawer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging what the parent of the view controller is, I found that it wasn't working because the parent of the view controller was a `UINavigationViewController`. Simply adding .parent again to `if let drawer = self.parent as? PulleyViewController {` fixed the issue.